# interpolating env variables in perl

Tags: perl, environment-variables

How to interpolate a environment variable before assigning to another variable.
For e.g. I am reading a line from input file which has environment variables. So I want to assign value of variable. I am not seeing the value of variable . My code is as below.

```
open (FH , "<", "$ARGV[0]")
   while ($line = <FH>)
$line2 = $line
}

print $line; ## prints $abc/ver
print $line2; ## prints $abc/ver

value of abc environment is username ;  So I am expecting to have $line2 value as below
print $line2 ; ## Should print username/ver
```

Comment: This is very well documented in the online manual.  Did you look at `%ENV`?

Comment: Don't use global vars (`FH`); use lexical vars (`my $FH`).

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the minimal solution:

```
$line2 =~ s/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g;
```

Of course, you might want to handle variables that aren't defined more cleanly, and you might want some kind of escape mechanism to prevent the special meaning of `$`.

Comment: @SwathiVutukuri: If it's working, then please accept the answer.